# Individualized bullet points are not transparent with \setbeamercovered{transparent}

Tags: beamer, itemize, bullets, transparent, uncover

I've a problem with my individualized bullet points in itemize. The text is transparent, but the bullet points aren't. It looks like the following slide:[image]

The images for the bullet points are defined in a beamer theme template through:

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{Dot_sub.png}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Dot_subsub.png}}
```

I want those defined images to also show up transperant in the beginning. How can I manage that?

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \vspace{-0cm}
\frametitle{Example slide}

\begin{itemize}

   \item <1->one
   \item <2->two
   \begin{itemize}
     \item <3->one
     \item <4->two
   \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: In particular the use of `\setbeamertemplate` in the second part of the answer to the proposed duplicate seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tikz to draw the bullet.

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\tikz[baseline=-.5ex] \filldraw [fill=yellow, draw=cyan, line width=.8pt] (0, 0) circle (2pt);}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\tikz[baseline=-.5ex] \fill [fill=blue!70] (0, 0) circle (2pt);}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> one
  \item<2-> two
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<3-> one
      \item<4-> three
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!